# FileReader onLoad not fireing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader

I have a simple react Component, This is the gist of the component:

```
<input ref={inputRef} type="file" hidden onChange={imageSelected} />
    <Button
      onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}
      icon="upload"
      size="big"
      style={{ margin: 0, marginRight: "2px" }}
      fluid
      color="green"
/>
```

This is the onChange function:

```
  const imageSelected = (ev) => {
    if (ev.target.files && ev.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.result);
      };
    }
  };
```

I'm not getting any output to the console, the onload is not fireing because, Why is that?

Comment: So where do you set the source? There is no reason for the load event to fire when you never tell it what to read.

Comment: It takes no parameters @epascarello

Comment: But you have to call a method to tell it what to read....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not tell it what to read. I assume it is an image from the naming so you would use readAsDataURL

```
const imageSelected = (ev) => {
  const file = ev.target.files && ev.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () { 
      cosole.log(reader.result);
    }, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

running example

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('[type="file"]');
const img = document.querySelector('img');

const imageSelected = (ev) => {
  const file = ev.target.files && ev.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () { 
      img.src = reader.result;
    }, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}

inp.addEventListener("change", imageSelected);
```

```html
<input type="file">
<img >
```

Comment: Oh, so i am pretty much stupid, Thanks lol, don't know how i missed this line, Debugging Time well spent i guess...